# include everything (including "ca.") up to next period or comma

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'll use the syntax used on regex101.com, but my code is in R.

take the following strings:

```
a) LVEF estimated to be highly impaired (ca. 20 %). blabla
b) LVEF highly impaired. blabla
```

My regex

```
(?=LVEF)([^,|.]*)
```

returns

```
a) LVEF estimated to be highly impaired (ca
b) LVEF highly impaired
```

Can I include "ca." but exclude every other "."?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a positive lookbehind `(?<=` is supported, you could add an optional part to match a dot if what precedes is `ca`

```
\bLVEF\b[^.]*(?:(?<=ca)\.)?
```

**Explanation**

- `\bLVEF\b` Match LVEF between word boundaries
- `[^.]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except a dot
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<=ca)\.` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is `ca`, then match a `.`
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aEnRdm/1)

**Edit:**

If you want to match `(ca. 20 %)` you could match any char except a dot or match a dot asserting what is directly to the left is `ca`

```
\bLVEF\b[^.]*(?:(?<=ca)\.[^.]*)?
```

- `\bLVEF\b` Match LVEF
- `[^.]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except a dot
- `(?:` Non caputure group

  - `(?<=ca)\.` Only match a dot when preceded by `ca`
  - `[^.]*` Match trailing 0+ occurrences of any char except a dot
- `)?` Close group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/urO9lS/1)

Comment: thanks! But in your linked Regex Demo the provided regex doesn't capture the "ca."?

Comment: @Beres It captures the dot for `ca.` v

Comment: You're right, of course! I should clarify: I'd like it to include everything until the next dot (so it should capture "ca. 20%)")

Comment: @Beres Do you mean like this? `\bLVEF\b(?:[^.]|(?<=ca)\.)*` https://regex101.com/r/I7Soeo/1

Comment: Yes! Although I reallyy don't understand why this works. The alternative "|" doesn't seem to make sense to me...

Comment: @Beres I have updated the pattern to make it a bit more efficient. It starts by matching any char except a dot. When it encounters a dot, it only matches it when what precedes it is ca. After matching ca, it will continue matching until the next occurrence of a dot.